# Cannot set property of undefined in AngualrJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to make a select all checkbox, that will on click select/deselect all other checkboxes on the page.

My HTML is like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-header">
            <th ng-if="!newTestSessionCtrl.formData.battery.id"><input type="checkbox" ng-click="newTestSessionCtrl.selectAllTests()" ng-model=".allSelected" /></th>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Available Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in newTestSessionCtrl.formData.battery.testDefinitions">
            <td ng-if="!newTestSessionCtrl.formData.battery.id"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.selected" ng-change="newTestSessionCtrl.optionToggled(); newTestSessionCtrl.validate()" /></td>
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{(row.duration / 60) | number:0}} minutes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is code from my controller:

```
    class NewTestSessionController {
        constructor($scope, $state, resources, NewTestSessionService, formats, AuthenticationService, toastr, momentTimezone, _) {
            this.allSelected = false;
        }

        selectAllTests() {
           let isSelected = true;
           if (this.allSelected) {
              isSelected = false;
           }
           angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions,  function(v) {
               v.checked = !isSelected;
               this.allSelected = !isSelected;
           });
        }

        optionToggled() {
           this.allSelected = true;
           angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions, function(v) {
               if(!v.checked) {
               this.allSelected = false;
           }
         });
      }
   }
```

The problem is with allSelected variable, when I click on select all checkbox I get error about being undefined:

[image]

Am I trying to access it in some wrong way? When I use debugger this variable is not undefined, so I am not sure if I am even looking on right place?
This problem should be easy to implement, but still I am not that good at Angular. Does someone sees the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrow Function` instead of `function()` declaration.

**Code**

```
selectAllTests() {
   let isSelected = true;
   if (this.allSelected) {
      isSelected = false;
   }
   //arrow function to make current this available inside function
   angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions,  (v) => {
       v.checked = !isSelected;
       this.allSelected = !isSelected;
   });
}

optionToggled() {
   this.allSelected = true;
   //arrow function to make current this available inside function
   angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions, (v) => {
       if(!v.checked) {
       this.allSelected = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Now I don't have any errors, but I guess my initial code wasn't good. Since non of the check-boxes are selected. ng-click triggers the function, but nothing happens. :( @PankajParkar

Answer (score 0):

It's the `scope` issue with `this`.

`this` scope is not available inside callback functions.

Assign `this` to another variable and use it inside the `callbacks`

Replace controller with this code.

```
class NewTestSessionController {
        constructor($scope, $state, resources, NewTestSessionService, formats, AuthenticationService, toastr, momentTimezone, _) {
            this.allSelected = false;
        }

        selectAllTests() {
           let _this = this;
           let isSelected = true;
           if (this.allSelected) {
              isSelected = false;
           }
           angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions,  function(v) {
               v.checked = !isSelected;
               _this.allSelected = !isSelected;
           });
        }

        optionToggled() {
           let _this = this;
           this.allSelected = true;
           angular.forEach(this.formData.battery.testDefinitions, function(v) {
               if(!v.checked) {
               _this.allSelected = false;
           }
         });
      }
   }
```